# query Creating Trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

im looking to create a trigger in mysql but finding it difficult, was hoping someone could help.

I have to ensure that the values for Cost have to be between 1500.00 and 2500.00 with a default of 2000.00 but i cannot think of how to use a trigger, as i know CHECK isnt supported.

Comment: You start with `create trigger`.  Have you done that?  The documentation contains examples:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Comment: i have looked at this but i dont understand how it works and how to properly program this.